# Calling storedprocedure with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure below:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE              SP_GET_NUMBER (p_cursor out sys_refcursor, departmentId in number, userId in number, documentTypeId in number)
as
regId integer;
sqlScript varchar2(60);
begin
sqlScript:='select registrationnumber_seq.nextval from dual';
execute immediate sqlScript into regid;
dbms_output.put_line('Nextval is: '||TO_CHAR(regid));
insert into roketsanuser.registrationnumbers
(id, departmentid, documenttypeid, registrationnumber, registrationstatus, status, updatedate, updateuserid, version)
values
(regId, null, null, regid, 0, 0, sysdate, 0, 0);
commit;
open p_cursor for
    select *
      from registrationnumbers reg
     where reg.id = regid;
end;
```

And i define that within annotations in my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "RegistrationNumber")
@Table(name = "REGISTRATIONNUMBERS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "REGISTRATIONNUMBER_SEQ", sequenceName = "REGISTRATIONNUMBER_SEQ")
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name = "SP_GET_NUMBER", query = "{call ?= SP_GET_NUMBER(:departmentId, :userId, :documentTypeId)}",
                                            callable = true, readOnly = true, resultClass = RegistrationNumber.class)
@EntityListeners( { BaseEntityListener.class })
public class RegistrationNumber extends BaseEntity
```

i call query in my Dao class:

```
public RegistrationNumber getNumberForIncomingPaperworkByStoredProcedure(EntityManager manager, RegistrationNumber registrationNumber)
{
    Session session = (Session)manager.getDelegate();
    org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl query = (SQLQueryImpl)session.getNamedQuery("SP_GET_NUMBER");

    query.setParameter("departmentId", ObjectUtil.isNotNull(registrationNumber.getDepartment()) ? registrationNumber.getDepartment().getId() : "");
    query.setParameter("userId", ObjectUtil.isNotNull(registrationNumber.getUser()) ? registrationNumber.getUser().getId() : "");
    query.setParameter("documentTypeId", ObjectUtil.isNotNull(registrationNumber.getDocumentType()) ? registrationNumber.getDocumentType().getId() : "");
    Collection list=query.list();
    return new RegistrationNumber();
}
```

But when i execute query occured exception:
<02-01-2013 10:04:24 o'clock EET>     
<02-01-2013 10:04:27 o'clock EET>    <10:04:27,811 ERROR [IncomingPaperworkMBean] EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query>

What might be the reason, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

With oracle I use the query syntax

`query = "call SP_GET_NUMBER(?, :departmentId, :userId, :documentTypeId)", hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true")}`

and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But nothing changed unfortunately